# How to prevent the browser using jQuery Form plugin changing to the form action url?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using OpenLayers and jQuery Mobile and trying to upload an image to the server and see a preview without page refresh.
I have this code in place:

Markup:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='image.php'>
  <input type="hidden" id="fid" name="fid">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" name="imagechooser" id="imagechooser">           </form>
<div id="imagepreview"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#imagechooser').on('change', function(event){        
    $("#imagepreview").html('');
    $("#imagepreview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({          
        target: '#imagepreview'
    }).submit();
});
```

Everything is working fine, file is uploaded and target is showing the image except that the browser changes to the page: `www.mypage.com/image.php` and there the page is empty with one word: "undefined", to see the target with the image I need to press the back button on the browser.

Is there any way I can prevent the browser from changing and showing that page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are submitting form through browser default submittal not ajax. This is causing the form `action` page to open. If you want ajax submittal use ajaxSubmit() method

Comment: I am actually following the post here: http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html and there it is working fine...not sure what you mean?!

Comment: here's the API for the form plugin  http://jquery.malsup.com/form/.... I don't do much in mobile environment, but plugin is the same in the demo

Comment: Thanks, I read this before posting here but I'm missing something.

Comment: I assumed from your "loading" gif you wanted to use ajax? Demo is not, it is opening action url

Comment: ok, thanks. got mixed up a bit.you meant call ajaxSubmit instead of ajaxForm. ok, all fixed.

Comment: I might be a bit confused too... when I clicked demo first time it did something different than second time. I do a lot of ajax though and have used form plugin in the past as an ajaxSumit method